# IOS XMLToObjectParser with array and attributes

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, parsing, object

I'm developing an iPhone application with xCode 4.5 for IOS 5+, I'm using ARC and Storyboard

I'm currently binding a list of XML items in a Array of `NSObject`.

For now, I can successfully extract the content of each node, but I need to read the attributes of a node, and to stock many node with the same name in an array.

I want to extract all the informations from an XML like this (values 1, 2, 3, respectively binded to properties `p1`, `p2`, `p3`) :

```
<Contact>
    <nom>Amanda</nom>
    <prenom>Pattison</prenom>
    <tel>3211234567</tel>
    <email>joe@smith.com</email>
    <array>
        <property name="p1" value="1"/>
        <property name="p2" value="2"/>
        <property name="p3" value="3"/>
    </array>
</Contact>
```

I'm currently using this XML (local hosted) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<contacts>
<Contact>
    <nom>Amanda</nom>
    <prenom>Pattison</prenom>
    <tel>3211234567</tel>
    <email>joe@smith.com</email>
</Contact>
<Contact>
    <nom>Kraft</nom>
    <prenom>Philippe</prenom>
    <tel>0728812121</tel> 
    <email/>
</Contact>
<Contact>
    <nom>Kent</nom>
    <prenom>Jerome</prenom>
    <tel>087832832</tel>
    <email>contact@jkraft.fr</email>
</Contact>
<Contact>
    <nom>Melbourne</nom>
    <prenom>Yannis</prenom>
    <tel>321-123-4567</tel>
    <email>joe@smith.com</email>
</Contact>
<Contact>
    <nom>Canberra</nom>
    <prenom>Amstrong</prenom>
    <tel>0728812121</tel>
    <email/>
</Contact>
<Contact>
    <nom>Namali</nom>
    <prenom>Pat</prenom>
    <tel>087832832</tel>
    <email>contact@jkraft.fr</email>
</Contact>
<Contact>
    <nom>Malani</nom>
    <prenom>John</prenom>
    <tel>321-123-4567</tel>
    <email>joe@smith.com</email>
</Contact>
<Contact>
    <nom>Pompidou</nom>
    <prenom>Juan</prenom>
    <tel>0728812121</tel>
    <email/>
</Contact>
<Contact>
    <nom>Cauht</nom>
    <prenom>Frederic</prenom>
    <tel>087832832</tel>
    <email>contact@jkraft.fr</email>
</Contact>
<Contact>
    <nom>Neil</nom>
    <prenom>Joe</prenom>
    <tel>321-123-4567</tel>
    <email>joe@smith.com</email>
</Contact>
<Contact>
    <nom>Youn</nom>
    <prenom>Eric</prenom>
    <tel>0728812121</tel>
    <email/>
</Contact>
<Contact>
    <nom>Lee</nom>
    <prenom>Pascal</prenom>
    <tel>087832832</tel>
    <email>contact@jkraft.fr</email>
</Contact>
</contacts>
```

And I'm using this parser :

-#XMLToObjectParser.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XMLToObjectParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate> {
    NSString *className;  
    NSMutableArray *items;  
    NSObject *item;  
    NSString *currentNodeName;
    NSMutableString *currentNodeContent;
}
- (NSArray *)items;
- (id)parseXMLAtURL:(NSURL *)url
       toObject:(NSString *)aClassName
     parseError:(NSError **)error;
@end
```

-#XMLToObjectParser.m

```
#import "XMLToObjectParser.h"

@implementation XMLToObjectParser

- (NSArray *)items
{
return items;
}

- (id)parseXMLAtURL:(NSURL *)url
       toObject:(NSString *)aClassName
     parseError:(NSError **)error
{

    items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    className = aClassName;
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];

    if([parser parserError] && error) {
        *error = [parser parserError];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{


    NSLog(@"Open tag: %@", elementName);
    if([elementName isEqualToString:className]) {
    // create an instance of a class on run-time
        item = [[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] init];
    }
    else {
        currentNodeName = [elementName copy];
        currentNodeContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
 didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    NSLog(@"Close tag: %@", elementName);
    if([elementName isEqualToString:className]) {
        [items addObject:item];

        item = nil;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:currentNodeName]) {
    // use key-value coding
        [item setValue:currentNodeContent forKey:elementName];
        currentNodeContent = nil;
        currentNodeName = nil;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
        NSLog(@"Found tag: %@", string);

[currentNodeContent appendString:string];
}

@end
```

The call :

```
tableau = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://10.20.100.12:8888/contacts.xml"];
XMLToObjectParser *myParser = [[XMLToObjectParser alloc] parseXMLAtURL:url toObject:@"Contact" parseError:nil];

 for(int i = 0; i < [[myParser items] count]; i++) {
        Contact *new = [[Contact alloc] init];
        new = (Contact *)[[myParser items] objectAtIndex:i];
        [tableau addObject:new];
        //[new release];
    }
```

Comment: use [TBXML][1] [1]:http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html

Comment: in fact, I wanted to use this library (XmlToObjectParser, and modify it to handle array and attributes datas.